# Git pushing as wrong user after updating OS

Tags: git, github, ssh, openssh

I updated my os to mavericks and now git is using an old ssh key (that I had believed was deleted) when pushing.
I've added an identity in ~/.ssh/config for github specifying the key to use.

When I execute the following from the terminal:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

The correct ssh key is used. However when I try push to a repo it's using an old ssh key. My local git config file is unchanged from when I git cloned the repo.

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you use `-v` to get verbose output from ssh (which should tell you where it's finding the key)?

Comment: If you are talking about the when the correct key is being used for the ssh command, the key is being located in ~/.ssh and it's the only key present in that folder.

Comment: That's fine, but does using `-v` confirm that? You say that ssh is using an old key, and `-v` will tell you what key ssh is using.

Comment: -v when doing git push doesn't give me any detail about the ssh key. Using -v with 'ssh -T git@github.com' details that it is using the config located in ~/.ssh and then using the appropriate identity which defines the correct ssh key location.

Comment: Is the problem something to do with `ssh-agent`?

Comment: If I run `ssh-add -l` It only lists one (correct) key. Is there anything else I should be checking for?

Comment: Also whoever is voting to close this question can you please comment your reason. This question does not meet the criteria for 'off topic' as defined in the help centre, as far as I can see.

Comment: Did you updated the ssh key on github site also to the new?

Comment: Yeah I added it to my git account. But even if it wasn't added, it should just deny access for the correct user. I can't see where it's even locating the ssh key it's using.

Comment: Okay if I change the remote origin url in my local .gitconfig from `https://github.com/<username>/<projectname>.git` to `git@github.com:<username>/<projectname>.git` I can push. Why would this work and not the auto-generated config I get from git clone?

Answer (score 0):

Set your git user info and it will show up on github as you :

```
git config --global user.name "Your name"
git config --global user.email your_email_on_github@example.com
```

Comment: This is already set correctly. It appears that the identity of the config file is used when the remote is set to the format as detailed above in the comments, but when it's in a https format git is not respecting the global git config for some reason. I have no idea why ;(